# How to restrict biographical info length and content in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

In WordPress there is Biographical Info under Profile. I would like to prevent the user from exceeding a maximum length of 400 characters. Also, the number of hyperlinks he can place in the biographical info should not exceed three. How do I do that? I am very familiar with JQuery, if that helps in this question. I am just a newbie with WordPress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Javascript side, you should attach the necessary events to the `description` field. You can load your script via the [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) hook, and you probably want to do all this in your handler for `admin_enqueue_scripts`, where you check for the passed `$hook_name`, which in this case is the page name. It is `user-edit.php` when an admin edits a user, and `profile.php` when the user edits their own information (in which case `IS_PROFILE_PAGE` will also be defined as `TRUE`).

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_description_validation_script');
function add_description_validation_script($pagename) {
   if ($pagename == 'profile.php' || $pagename == 'user-edit.php') {
      wp_enqueue_script('description_validation', '/path/to/description_validation.js');
   }
}
```

For the PHP side, you need the `pre_user_description` filter. This gives you the current biographical text, and your function can change this and return something else.

```
add_filter('pre_user_description', 'sanitize_description');
function sanitize_description($description)
{
   // Do stuff with the description
   return $description;
}
```

If, instead of silently changing the description, you want to show an error, you should look into the `user_profile_update_errors` hook. There you can validate the given data and return error messages to the user.

You probably want to [wrap this all up in a plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin), so you can keep the code together and easily enable or disable it. A plugin is just a file in the `/wp-content/plugins/` directory, most likely in a subdirectory named after your plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! This surely points me in the right direction!